# C++ passing a string array by reference

Tags: c++, arrays, string, function, parameter-passing

I'm new in C++, and I'm trying to write a program that using only function (no vector or template) should be able to read an extarnal file and save everything in one array.
To dimension my array i first read the total number of lines in the file, and based on taht I dimensioned my array.
Then I re-read all the lines in the file and I started to store them in the array.
Everything went well.
But when I got the code and tried to make us a feature I got stuck.
I can not find any way to pass the array by reference.
Each time I find a variety of errors.
Can someone help me please?
Thank you

```
while (!infile.eof())
{
// read the file line by line
getline (infile,line);
 ++lines_count2;

// call a function that take out the tags from the line
parseLine(&allLines[lines_count], lines_count2, line);

}   // end while



    // FUNCTION PARSE
    // Within parseHTML, strip out all of the html tags leaving a pure text line.
    void parseLine(string (&allLines)[lines_count], int lines_count2, string line)
{
// I don-t take empty lines
if (line!="")
{

// local var
string del1="<!DOCTYPE", del2="<script";
int eraStart=0, eraEnd=0;

    // I don't take line that start with <!DOCTYPE
    eraStart = line.find(del1);
    if (eraStart!=std::string::npos)
        line.clear();

    // I don't take line that start with  <script
    eraStart = line.find(del2);
    if (eraStart!=std::string::npos)
    line.clear();

    //out
    cout << "Starting situation: " << line << "\n \n";

    // A. counting the occourence of the character ">" in the line
    size_t eraOccur = count(line.begin(), line.end(), '<');
    cout << "numero occorenze" << eraOccur  << "\n \n";

    // declaring the local var
    string str2 ("<"), str3 (">");

    // B. loop in the line for each occurence...looking for <  and >  position
    for (int i=0; i<eraOccur; i++)
    {

        // looking for position char  "<"
        eraStart = line.find(str2);
        if (eraStart!=string::npos)
        {
            cout << "first 'needle' found at: " << eraStart << '\n';

            // looking for position char  ">"
            eraEnd = line.find(str3);
            if (eraEnd!=string::npos)
            cout << "second 'needle' found at: " << eraEnd << '\n';
            eraEnd=eraEnd-eraStart+1;

            //delete everything between < and >
            cout << "start " << eraStart  << " end " <<  eraEnd << "\n \n";     
            line.erase(eraStart, eraEnd);
        }
    }

cout << "memo situation: " << line << "\n \n";

// C. memorize the result into an array
allLines[lines_count2] = line;

}       // end if
```

}

Comment: Watch out with .eof() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array was declared as `string allLines[lines_count]` you should should declare the function as

`void parseLine(string* allLines, int lines_count2, string line)`  or

`void parseLine(string allLines[], int lines_count2, string line)`

and call the function as `parseLine(allLines, lines_count2, line)`

Comment: Yesss Youda !  yesss....
Thank you.
I was looking to different solution like:
'void parseLine(string (&allLines)[lines_count], int lines_count2, string line)'
But they didn't work